# How much do silver weapons cost?

Tags: weapons, adnd-1e, pricing, special-materials

Silver weapons are clearly a thing, as many monster stat blocks claim they can be hit with silver weapons. But I don’t see how much they cost.

So, how much does a silver weapon cost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search of the *Player's Handbook*, *Dungeon Master's Guide*, and *Monster Manual* for *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons* probably led you to the same conclusion: beyond the entry for **arrow, silver, single** that costs 1 g.p. (*Player's Handbook* 35) and the Items On A Robe Of Useful Items table entry for **dagger, silver** (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 227) there appears to be in the three main books no other silver weapons.

In other words, the DM must make up his own material or use material from a source beyond the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, *Player's Handbook*, and *Monster Manual*.

Silver weapons are discussed in [this 2016 blog post](http://deltasdnd.blogspot.com/2016/01/silver-weapons.html) that traces the evolution of the inclusion of silver weapons from original *Dungeons & Dragons* through *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5*, and it reaches the same conclusion.

Comment: For reference, PHB prices a single arrow at 2sp. A silver arrow is 1gp.  So 10 times the price for silver. A PHB dagger is 2GP. Unearthed Arcana has a +1 dagger GP Sale Value set at 500 gp. So 250 times the price for magic. Another weapon to consider is cold iron which causes double damage on ghasts or damage on night hags.

Comment: @ExcessOperatorHeadspace Changed the price of the silver arrow to 1 g.p. Thank you. I'm not including the other information because it's really up to the DM if silvering other weapons should multiply the price of those weapons like the price of an arrow is multiplied… and the same for straight-up buying other magic weapons. If a price were given for the *DMG*'s silver dagger, though, I'd totally add that as a possibility. Thank you again.